# FileNotFoundError, even though the file exists

Tags: python-3.x

I've made a small program in Python that reads text files. However, I keep getting the **FileNotFoundError**, even though the file exists. The seemingly problematic code of my code looks like this:

```
fileEntered = False

while not fileEntered:
    try:
        fileName = input("Enter file name: ")
        file = open(fileName, "r")
        fileEntered = True
        fileContents = file.readlines()
        file.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found. Please try again.")
```

When asked for the file, I enter *randomtext.txt* (which is located in the same folder as the program), but it keeps throwing the FileNotFoundError (it keeps printing the line in the **except** block).

Comment: @dmitryro: PYTHONPATH is irrelevant for `open()`, it's only for imports.

Comment: How are you running the program?  In an IDE?  From the command line?

Comment: The current working directory is used for relative filenames in `open()`. Can you `print(os.getcwd())` and ensure you are in the right working directory. You can change to the right current working directory with `os.chdir()`. Or use an absolute pathname in `open()`.

Answer (score 0):

Will be able to tell whether you are getting Win Error 2 or Win Error 3 when you are opening the file?  If Win Error 2, then the problem may be related to your current working directory. That means, the scripting is looking into a different folder eventhough the file exists. If you are getting Win Error 3, then it is a different issue.

I've amended your code to get exact error code.

```
fileName = input("Enter file name: ") 
file = open(fileName, "r") 
fileContents = file.readlines()
 print(fileContents) 
file.close()
```

I am getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '454544.txt' (when there is not file exists - Errno 2]. When I tried with full path or relative path, the script works fine. Please try and get the actual error so that you can progress.  If the file exists in your current working directory, then the script will work properly. Please change the working directory to try.

Comment: I guess the above will help the question to see if it is win error 2 or 3. If win error 2, then he has to change his working directory or give the full path. This is the answer to his query.

Comment: @David, Can you please try and let us know your results?